# meaning of the statement

Tags: c, pointers, char, c-strings

I have many times come across the statement `char* ch = "hello";`.

I understand that `char* ch` tells that `ch` is a pointer towards a  `char`. But what does assigning **hello** to ch mean ?

I cannot undestand this ? please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means `ch` is a pointer to a character. When you do `char* ch = "hello"`  `ch` will be pointing to the first character i.e. character `h`. To point to the second character, you can do `ch + 1` or `ch[1]`. Note that ideally the type of `ch` should have been `const char*` as you can not write to the pointed memory location.

Comment: Note that this const-removing special conversion is deprecated in C++98/C++03, and removed in C++0x (i.e., with a conforming C++0x compiler, will not compile).

Comment: Any specific reason for downvote? Is there something wrong with the answer?

Answer (score 3):

String literals are stored statically somewhere inside the program binary. They are most likely loaded into a readonly 'data' section in memory, but this is undefined behavior.

Assigning a string literal simply passes the address of the first byte; in this case, `char* ch` points to the 'h' in "hello".

**Note:** Modifying static strings is undefined behavior!  While you can get a pointer, any assignment is dangerous.

Comment: ...so, it should be const char * ch

Answer (score 1):

There are several things happening here.

`"hello"` is equal to `{ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' }`. I.e., it is an array of characters. Arrays can be implicitly converted to the corresponding pointer type. So the statement here really creates a (static) array of characters, and assigns the pointer to the first element to the variable `ch` (bad naming, by the way).

Answer (score 0):

the statement compiles to:

```
080483b4 <main>:
 80483b4:   55                      push   %ebp
 80483b5:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80483b7:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
 80483ba:   c7 45 fc 94 84 04 08    movl   $0x8048494,-0x4(%ebp)
 80483c1:   c9                      leave  
 80483c2:   c3                      ret
```

the string at 0x8048494 is "hello\0" as seen here from xxd:

```
0000490: 0100 0200 6865 6c6c 6f00 0000 011b 033b  ....hello......;
```